# Cannot compile @Injectable in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

recently I upgraded to:

- angular-cli 6.0.7
- angular 6.0.3

I have generated a new project and wanted to use the new Injectable decorator.
When decorating a class:

```
  @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class SomeService {
       constructor() { }
   }
```

I get following compile error:

> Argument type {providedIn: "root"} is not assignable to parameter
>   type {providedIn: Type | "root" | null} & InjectableProvider 
>       Checks TypeScript called function parameters , return values , assigned expressions to be of correct type.

When I write the class like:

```
 @Injectable
 export class SomeService {
    constructor() { }
 }
```

I get a runtime error with the same message.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure about the new providedIn option, but the latter one must be @Injectable()

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201189/webstorm-argument-type-providedin-root-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-typ

Comment: Totally on point! - Thanks!
I am still trying to figure out why the auto generated class from the angular-cli does not compile?

Comment: @yurzui thanks! I googled with the same error message but could not find anything...

Comment: try this @Injectable()